# Listening for events from a server, Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, web-services, google-chrome-extension, notifications, server-sent-events

I am creating a Chrome extension that will notify users when there is an update to their profile on a service I am running. What's the best way for a server to send updates to a notification?

Ideally I'd like to use something like Server-Sent events to push notifications to the extension. I believe the correct way would be to keep the extension open in the background to listen and act upon messages sent through Server-Sent events, but there aren't many resources on how to accomplish this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions can access the GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) services directly through [`chrome.gcm`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) API, it enables extensions to send and receive messages through GCM Service.

Take a look at [`chrome.gcm`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/gcm) and [Implementing GCM Client on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client), there are very detailed samples.